# Dll issue in Aspnet Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core-mvc-2.0

I am getting System.Web.Http error while I am converting mvc5 application to aspnet core.
I am using class library in an existing project and also not using directly this .dll in class library.

> error- Could not load file or assembly 'System.Web.Http,
>   Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or
>   one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try reinstalling the NuGet package

From the package manager console, type:

Update-Package Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Core -reinstall